# How are images cached when loaded via php script

Tags: php, javascript, image, caching

I have a php script acting as a random image generator. The script queries the database for the user's images, and returns the path to one, at random. Here is the portion of the  code responsible for returning the image, once the path has been chosen.

```
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
echo file_get_contents($path);
```

I am calling it from the client like so

```
image.src = "/database/getRandomImage.php";
```

Every time I refresh the page I get a new image at random. However, if I call `getRandomImage.php` multiple times for side by side images, they will all be the same image. If I add a random property to the call like so

```
image.src = "/database/getRandomImage.php?path=" + Math.random() * 100;
```

The pictures become random. I take this to mean that the browser is caching them based on the random property I passed. The problem is this property has nothing to do with the actual image. Two different images might get cached as the same image, and the same image might not be retrieved from the cache. Is there any way for `getRandomImage.php` to inform the browser about the picture it is sending back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have `getRandomImage` be a PHP function, which returns a path to the image.  You can render the page out with the random image paths already filled in.

```
<img src="<? echo getRandomImage() ?>">
```

Then you can actually serve your images with real cache headers, and your bandwidth wont be getting hammered so hard.

Do this on the server side while the page is rendering, not after.  Doing it after is more work and, as you are finding out, is more complicated too.

Comment: Would that not be slower requesting the image name THEN requesting the image?

Comment: I suppose, in theory.  But that is just how the web works.  An image has a specific URL that can be access to download that image data.  And if fetching an image url from your database is really a deal breaking performance problem, then you very likely have much bigger issues.  But if you can't use caching, because you dont have unique urls for you images, then it will likely be much slower after the first time they see that image.

Comment: It's not fetching from the DB that is slow, it's the http request I was worried about (which I suppose is gone now). Essentially anything involving Ajax is so slow, as if it takes 3/4 of a second just to kick in. I am assuming with this solution, of setting the image while loading the page, that problem no longer exists

Comment: Yep, that's the idea.  Figuring out the path when the page is rendered means you do not need an AJAX request to figure it out.

Comment: I just hit another conceptual barrier (I really dislike asynchronous `image` behavior). My code works in two stages. First the code is dynamically loaded via `AJAx` as `type : javascript` (I'm working on using `<script>` instead to bypass eval) next, when ready, there is a call to `load = function(){...}` which loads the image. But how do I put the `<img src="<? echo getRandomImage() ?>">` in there?

Comment: Generate a JSON array of image urls that you will need as part of that script.  `var imageUrls = ['/abc123.png', '/def456.png];` then use JS to load them.  If you can, figure out these paths whenever you are doing anything server side already.

Answer (score 1):

The caching has nothing to do with the PHP script; it happens at the browser.

Try adding this to the script, to try and force the browser to not cache it (from [PHP website](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)):

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");  // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");    // Date in the past
```

Comment: I would prefer it if a cache version could be used instead.

Comment: Well if you want the same path to be used for multiple images, you CANNOT allow caching.

Comment: @Squeegy I realize that now. I'll use your [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220498/how-are-images-cached-when-loaded-via-php-script/8220703#8220703) instead

Answer (score 0):

Just make `randomImage.php` redirect to a seeded version if it isn't present.

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['seed']))
{
      header("Location: randomImage.php?seed="+rand());
      exit;
}
```

Feel free to make the randomizer more random.

Comment: I don't understand, how is this different than seeding it clientside?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers expect that the same will always represent the same image.  And I think that even headers that force no caching at all wont even stop the browser from reusing the image on the same page.  So a image source that is different each time you call it is pretty counter intuitive.

Cache busting is probably your best bet.  That means like you random hack there, although there is ways to do it better.  For instance, appending an increasing integer to the current time.  This way you never duplicate urls.

```
var count = 0;
var now = new Date().getTime();
imgs[0].src = "/database/getRandomImage.php?" + (count++) + now;
imgs[1].src = "/database/getRandomImage.php?" + (count++) + now;
imgs[2].src = "/database/getRandomImage.php?" + (count++) + now;
```

But really, you may want to rethink your strategy here, because it sounds a little fishy.

Comment: I don't know what images I have client side, they are all stored in a database. I have to query it before I can load it. I just assumed it would be faster to query and retrieve the image in one go, rather than querying, getting the path, then setting it as `img.src=`

Comment: Given that bit of info, I added another answer that might be better.