# How does client load and cache images available only in the database

Tags: php, javascript, database, image

I have never used a database (MySQL) before for my website, and I have hit a conceptual barrier as to how to load images.

- I can query the database for picture paths using AJAX, then use `<image src=/path/to/image.jpg>`, but I don't want to call both AJAX and `<image>`
- I can use a php script like so `<image src='getImage.php'>` but that leads to problems with caching as I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220498/how-are-images-cached-when-loaded-via-php-script)

Neither of those options seems ideal to. This seems like a very basic operation since the client must make queries to the database before knowing where the file is located. I would appreciate input from more advanced programmers as to how this should be carried out.

Comment: How are you trying to use the images? Not sure the relationship between your DB and images...

Comment: @JonathonReinhart The database has a table called 'picture' which has a ID (primary key), an owner (foreign key), and the path where the image is saved.

Comment: I followed your link but found no problems with caching. Instead I found a misunderstanding of how URLs work. So.. do you want to cache or don't you? (FYI, URL's are like file paths on the hard disk. A single file path can only point to a single file, same with URL).

Comment: @slebetman in the link, the `image.src = "/database/getRandomImage.php"`, at least on my computer, gets cached as a single file, even though `getRandomImage` is returning a different image every time.

Comment: It saves a PATH? So just have PHP grab the path from the DB when creating the page (assuming the page containing the images is also PHP).

Comment: @Mike I think I got it now, Squeegy mentioned a [similar solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220498/how-are-images-cached-when-loaded-via-php-script/8220703#8220703). I think my 'conceptual barrier' is trying to add the pictures AFTER the page has finished loading, rather than during.

Comment: @Mike I'm going to put the gist of this discussion as an answer

Comment: @puk: On your computer getRandomImage.php is indeed a single file and NOT an image but is plain text. Running `php getRandomImage.php` executes that text as PHP code but you filesystem knows nothing about this.

Comment: @slebetman so basically, as far as my browser is concerned, it's loading the image `getRandomImage.php.jpg`

Comment: @puk: Basically, yes. That's why it caches it and does not load random images. To force it to load random images you basically have to override this default behavior and tell it not to cache it. Which is why you have the choice of either having the images random or having them cached - cannot do both. It also explains why adding random characers in the URL name work because the browser will see them as different "files".

Comment: @puk: Also note that jpeg files are not required to end in '.jpg' and php files are not required to end in '.php'. Those are just conventions for humans. When you declare the content-type as jpeg then the browser will believe you and ignore the file extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'conceptual barrier' I have encountered, as it turns out, is the fact that I assumed I had to load the images **after** I loaded the page, and not **during**. Thanks to [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/813388/mike) and [Squeegy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62076/squeegy), turns out the best solution would be something like

```
<img src="<? echo getRandomImage() ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right, you can do this:

```
<image src='getImage.php?id={unique_identifier}'>
```

Since the id will change for each image, you will not have the cache problem

If you don't have an id for the images, you can just place any random number there

Comment: Yes, that's the solution (hack) I used [initially](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220498/how-are-images-cached-when-loaded-via-php-script/8220546#8220546) the problem is that the client doesn't know what image it is retrieving, so the same image might get two unique identifiers.

Comment: Why would same image get two uid?

Comment: B/c the id's are stored serverside, and the client has no knowledge of it, so the uid's would have to be randomly assigned (ie. a counter), or, as I foolishly thought, the server had to be queried, the file path retrieved, then the image loaded.

Comment: If it's possible to change it at this time, you may wish to consider sorting the table by the ID (descending), grab the top one (since it's descending, it starts at the biggest ID) and increase it by 1. This way you'd get a descending ID where each is one larger than the last, ensuring they'd be unique.

Comment: @Mike It's definitely possible to assign unique user x picture IDs, that way, if the user ID is known, picture IDs could start at 1..n for each user ID. I will take it under consideration, but won't use this 'optimization' until later on.